# How to sum / get total All price on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sum

I want to showing all total item price. I only have column like this

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |     qty    |     price  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |     10     |     5000   | // total 50000
+----+------------+------------+
|  2 |     2      |     2000   | // total 4000
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |     10     |     1000   | // total 10000    ---> All total item is : 64000 <--- i need this!!!
+----+------------+------------+
```

I want to add my controller like this

```
 $total  = Pencairan::where('indukpencairan_id', 1)->sum(('price')*('qty'));
```

but I get this error:

> A non-numeric value encountered

What's wrong with my sum? Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try single quoting the expression with `DB::raw` which you actually want to sum here:

```
$total  = Pencairan::where('indukpencairan_id', 1)->sum(DB::raw('price*qty'));
```

Comment: its like name this colomn . its not solution . colomn not found

Comment: @AdhikMulat I'm sorry, you will need to use `DB::raw` here.

Comment: @KUMAR It is the price of all items listed in the table.